# Is this the correct way to prove if and only if type of propositions?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Suppose I have the proposition:

> **An object satisfies A if and only if B**

Is this the following way to prove this?

> $(\Rightarrow)$ If direction. Assume B is true, show A
>
> $(\Leftarrow)$ only if direction. Assume A is true, show B

There seems a bit of reversal of logic I can't wrap my head around after waking up. Short term memoryloss perhaps.

Comment: This looks correct. $A$ if $B$ means that assume $B$ is true, and show $A$ is true. Only if is the other way. So  your thinking is right.

Comment: I would say that the "forward" direction $\Rightarrow$ is only if, not if, and the backward direction $\Leftarrow$ is "if". So I would switch those two symbols. Otherwise you got it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right with what you say. Basically:

$$A\iff B \sim (A\implies B)\wedge (B\implies A)$$

So the best way to understand how to properly prove a iff is that you have to prove both directions, either in a direct way, by contrapositive or contradiction, depending strictly on the case.